# What amount of memory is free for us to use it(C++ , windows 7)

Tags: c++, memory-management

When dynamically allocating some objects or variables in C++ (I'm using Windows 7).. is there a way to find out how much memory(in bytes) is there free for us to use so we can prevent a crash?  Also I would like to know is it OS-specific? If it is, what's the difference for example between windows and some other widely used OS?

Comment: Failing to allocate memory does not cause a crash. Failing to properly handle that error causes a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily find out how much free memory there is. Even the concept of free memory is unclear, since the OS may offer disk-backed virtual memory. Essentially, on modern personal computers and up, the main problem isn't running out of memory but running out of *fast* memory, getting into a regime with much page file activity and things really slowing down.

If a dynamic memory allocation fails in C++, you get a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

You can install a so called **new-handler** to deal with an out-of-memory situation. It can log something and fail, or perhaps release some memory from a crisis fund (so to speak). In some cases this may allow a controlled program exit.

---

Even if you do find out much memory would have been available at the time of the checking call, by the time you get to your allocation some other process or thread in your process may have used up much of that, so that the allocation still fails.

Thus, you need to either be prepared for allocation failure, or design for so reasonable memory consumption that you feel safe in just ignoring the issue.

---

Thus, the answer to your question …

> “is there a way to find out how much memory(in bytes) is there free for us to use so we can prevent a crash?”

is “no”  – crashing (presumably due to not handling the `bad_alloc` exception) can not be prevented by checking available memory beforehand.

Comment: @Mgetz: yes, you can use that information to try to not stress the system. but it's futile to use it to guarantee that some allocation will succeed. because the information is stale, out of date, already when you get it. Also, the free memory available via C++ `new` can be larger or smaller even if everything stood still after the checking call. That's because (1) it does sub-allocation, where the sub-allocator may have much free memory, and (2) it does sub-allocation (yes, again) which has some overhead, using memory to manage memory.

Comment: @Mgetz: `VirtualAlloc` doesn't reserve RAM, it reserves *address space*. Committing it later can fail.

Comment: @Mgetz: a guaranteed no-fail reserve is equivalent to an allocation. can you explain, in the scheme you envision, what the advantage is of requiring a later commit call that is not allowed to do anything?

Comment: -1 for failure to read the [`VirtualAlloc` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Fundamentally this answer is wrong, it is not supported by the documenation or any of Mark Russinovich's talks on windows memory internals.

Comment: @MGetz: it's a pardaox: in under to misunderstand it you already have to have failed to apply elementary reasoning. so you didn't answer the question about the purpose of a commit that can't do anything. but think about it  --  and do start to provide **references** for claims of that sort.

Comment: Actually I did in chat, a reserve is not a commit and should NEVER be confused with one as you seem to be doing, a reserve is just that saying "I will use this memory space don't load stuff here" thus placing no load on the system. The OS thus responds "yes I can reserve that for you" or "no I can't." If the former is returned then the OS has reserved the space and can commit that when requested in the process memory space without failure.

Comment: [Marc Russinovich's talk at teched part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405) and [Part 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL406)

Comment: @MGetz: I think maybe you're confusing viritual addresses with physical memory. Still even if that's what you're doing you're not making any sense, since a reserve whose following commit can't fail, is the same as an allocation with a do-nothing commit. It's just meaningless. And please don't post videos. I have neither the time nor the bandwidth to look at that, trawling for your possible misunderstandings. Quote and link to **TEXT**, please.

Comment: Re the "you can't reserve following a commit" above, that gives an *impression* that I have written that one can. I have not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends not upon the OS but upon the processor architecture.The amount of memory available to a process is determined by the number of address pins available in the processor.

If you are about to allocate a contiguous space,say array, that can be more difficult and a very less number of cells can be available.

The best approach would be allow the error to happen.`malloc` returns `NULL` in case of no memory available/error.Check that case take necessary recovery action.

Comment: It also depends of the OS and some configuration. On windows 32 bits if you do not unable "LARGEADDRESSAWARE" your process can allocate only 2Gb. With "LARGEADDRESSAWARE" you can go up to 3Gb. A 32b process on windows 64 can go up to 2g without large address aware and up to 4G with.

Comment: This is clearly not true in a number of respects. On my old Win95 machine more memory was available to my processes once I installed another 32MB of RAM but I didn't change the number of address pins available in the processor. Also the OS does make a difference. Even a 32-bit process _can) benefit from additional address space when booting between (say) 32-bit and 64-bit version of Windows XP.